# The memory address of constants in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, constants, memory-address

I'm learning about pointers in C and I've got a few questions.
Here's a piece of code just for an example.

```
int var = 300;
char s[] = "Clang";
char *p  = "Wonder";
```

I know that all the variables have their addresses in memory.
The variables like `var` and `s` and `p` have their own addresses in memory.

But I wonder if constants have memory addresses as well.

Do `300`,`"Clang"`, `"Wonder"` themselves have memory addresses?

Comment: `300` is not an object: it does not have an address; `"Clang"` nd `"Wonder"` both are objects in their own right (with type array of 6 and 7 char respectively) and have their own addresses. *You copy the address of `"Wonder"` into `p` in your code.*

Comment: The C standard describes a computation model that is used to specify how programs behave. In that model, the constant `300` is not an object and has no address, whereas the strings cause the creation of static arrays, which are objects and do have addresses. However the C standard does not require implementations to follow the model exactly. They may optimize a program and generate different code as long as the *observable behavior* of the program, such as its output, is the same…

Comment: … In the code you show `"Clang"` might not exist with an address if the compiler can initialize `s` without it (possibly by using immediate operands in instructions) or can remove `s` from the program at least to some extent. `"Wonder"` is less likely to be removed but it depends on how `p` is used.

Comment: Another distinction between `s` and `p` is that on all (with few exceptions) `"Wonder"` will be stored in the `.rodata` section and cannot be modified. Therefore the characters in `"Wonder"` cannot be modified.  With `s`, `"Clang"` is simply used to initialize a regular array and the contents of `s` can be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only objects and functions have addresses in C. Named variables are objects. A string literal `"Wonder"` used by itself is an object, an array of 7 characters (i.e. `char[7]`) - the 6 visible characters and the terminating null character - and therefore may have an address. The literal `"Clang"` is a borderline case here, strictly speaking it does not have an address because it is not an object but just a special initializer syntax.

The C model is quite unlike Python programming language, where

```
a = 300
```

`a` is a name that has no address, whereas `300` is an object that has an address.

The *may* is because while C says that an object or function has an address, many compilers optimize code, creating an executable that does not follow the strict C abstract machine; therefore an object might have an address only if you observe it.

Comment: Re “strictly speaking it does not have an address”: Strictly speaking it does have an address, in the C model before optimization. The C standard clearly says the string literal in source text is used to define a static array with the indicated contents, even if it is used to initialize another array.

Comment: `"Wonder"` is an array of 7 characters, just saying, more idiomatically: `"Wonder"` has type `/*read-only*/char[7]`

Comment: @pmg oops :)) I confused clang and wonder in my answer originally and the number 6 remained.

Answer (score 3):

Memory usage of variables and constants is a matter of compiler implementation. In practice, constants defined like this:

```
const *foo = "bar";
const int answer = 42;
```

will usually occupy memory and have addresses. That is, some place in the program's address space at run-time you'll find the sequence of bytes representing the text "bar" and the sequence of bytes representing the number 42.

However, because of the aggressive optimization done by modern compilers, it's plausible that some constants may have no run-time existence at all. For example, in a snippet like this:

```
const int foo = 3;
int x = foo * 4;
```

it's conceivable that, if `foo` is never used anywhere else, the compiler might (in effect) convert this to:

```
int x = 12;
```

and `foo` won't even exist at runtime.

Incidentally, many developers think of C pre-processor macros as "constants":

```
#define PI 3.14159
```

These usually don't occupy memory at run-time, because they are substituted into the code at compilation time.

Comment: this does not quite address the question of whether value 300 has an address.

Comment: I think it does now. But it's possible to be so precious about questions like this, that you end up with an answer that only a compiler designer would understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations place objects in "sections" usually called .text (code), .data - initialized data, .bss - zeroed data, .rodata - read only data.